# Single-Antenna-Single-Pass SAR interferometry

Tags: remote-sensing, radar

As I understand, for elevation mapping using InSAR, one typically requires an out-of-plane baseline to create the required phase difference between images to detect objects at height. This usually requires either multiple satellites flying in formation or waiting for a repeat pass of a single satellite.

This paper, [A New Single-Pass SAR Interferometry Technique with a Single-Antenna for Terrain Height Measurements](https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/11/9/1070), suggests that one could achieve this in a single pass (along-track interferometry), if we are able to image at a high squint angle. The idea is that a grazing-angle difference is still present in the along-track case when squint angle is high. This is not the case for broadside imaging.

However apart from this paper, I was not able to find any other sources to cross-reference the viability of this approach, nor does it seem that anyone else has reproduced the results. The mathematical principle behind seem sound to me. If it works, why is this concept not being used more often, and if it doesn't actually work, where is the error in the logic?